# Incremental transformation using Delta live tables

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables, elt

I'm attempting to build an incremental data processing pipeline using delta live tables.
The aim to stream data from a source multiple times in a day and join the data within the specific increment only.

I'm using autoloader to load the data incrementally from source.

I've taken a sample of 2 tables which I'm attempting to join with each other and produce a gold table.
When I run the pipeline for the first time, the tables are joined correctly and the count of records in the gold table is correct.

In the next step, I attempt to load 2 records each in the input tables and reran the entire pipeline. I was expecting the final table row count to be incremented by 2. However I found that the number was > 2. On closer inspection, I realized that even though only 2 records were streamed in for each of the input tables, the join occurred with the entire table.
Is there a way I can have only the delta of each file be joined with each other rather than have the join occur over the entire table?

The joining step looks like this.

```
def load_table_to_gold(sqlstmt,temp,outtable):  
    @dlt.table(name=f"GOLD_{outtable}",temporary=temp, comment=f"This is my gold table GOLD_{outtable}")
    def gold_cold():
        golddf = spark.sql("SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, c.mobile_number, o.order_id, o.total_amount, c.ingested_date FROM STREAM LIVE.SILVER_Cust AS c INNER JOIN STREAM LIVE.SILVER_Orders AS o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id")
        return golddf
```

As you can see from the pic, it shows that the 2 incoming tables streamed in 2 records each, however, the join that occurred spat out 19 records into the Gold table.[image]